# Where are distinguished fields are stored in BizTalk?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2010

When I am creating a Schema, I want to some fields are to be distinguished fields using in Orchestration, Where these distinguished fields are stored in BizTalk application?

One more question is what is XPath aliases? Where we can find in BizTalk ?

Comment: Did the below answer help, or are you still confused?

Answer (score 0):

A distinguished field is put in the annotation under the record in the schema where you added the distinguished field.

e.g.

```
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
    <b:properties>
      <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='ContactNo' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Contact_1' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Contact-No' and namespace-uri()='']" /> 
    </b:properties>
  </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

XPath aliases are basically what a distinguished field is, it is a friendly name you can use instead of having to know the XPath, see the example above where the I have distinguished a field called Contact-No

The distinguished field can be found in the Schema Editor, right click on the field you want to distinguish, select Promote, Show Promotions

[image]

Then make sure you are on the Distinguished Fields tab (rather than Property Fields) and Add those fields you want to distinguish

[image]